# Code with Renderer2 in Angular Universal not work

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm trying to do the following, I have an  component and inside it I have other divs elements, among other things,
I want to delete the example tag and pass all the child elements to the parent element in order

Code work in Angular4(dev work,not work in universal, not work with aot);

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    var nativeElement: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement,
    parentElement: HTMLElement = nativeElement.parentElement;
    // move all children out of the element
    while (nativeElement.firstChild) {
      parentElement.insertBefore(nativeElement.firstChild, nativeElement);
    }
    // remove the empty element(the host)
    parentElement.removeChild(nativeElement);
  }
```

I pass the way to modify the dom with Renderer2, because the documentation specifies it, but nevertheless the following code does not work, is stuck in an infinite loop.

```
export class AppSidebarFooter {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,private renderer:Renderer2) { }

  //wait for the component to render completely
  ngOnInit(): void {
    var nativeElement: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement,
    parentElement: HTMLElement = nativeElement.parentElement;
    // move all children out of the element
    while (nativeElement.firstChild) {
      this.renderer.insertBefore(parentElement,nativeElement.firstChild,nativeElement);
      this.renderer.removeChild(nativeElement,nativeElement.firstChild);        
      //parentElement.insertBefore(nativeElement.firstChild, nativeElement);
    }
    // remove the empty element(the host)
    this.renderer.removeChild(parentElement,nativeElement);
  }
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing the DOM directly. create *ngFor and data instead to drive the UI. NodeJS doesn't have a document object. any direct or indirect reference to it will make NodeJS fail

Comment: I am using rederer2 to avoid access directly modify the dom.

Comment: your code will fail here : var nativeElement: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement,
    parentElement: HTMLElement = nativeElement.parentElement; cause that implies accessing the DOM which NodeJs doesn't know about

Comment: how should it be done? I can not find an example